# Selenium Python: Write and read data from Json

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

Hi I’m using Selenium in Python and would like to write the data inside a json file. The informations I want to write and read is related to names, that are taken from a for-loop.
But how can I read and write from a json file (called names.json) with this structure with Selenium Python?:

```
{
    "ignored" : ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the json module of the standard library?

Comment: No. My problem is I can’t do it. Because I don’t know how to do the code using the structure I wrote

Comment: you need to look up  and understand python dictionary if you cant make the structure. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries. then save dictionary using json module.